# Windows 2008 Server User Account with limited access

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows

I'd like to set up a user account for a friend of mine on a windows 2008 VPS I have.  I want them to be able to setup web and ftp sites in IIS, but i don't want them to be able to mess with websites that are not theirs or create or alter new users.  Is this possible and if so, what group do I put them in.

thanks,
fregas

Answer (score 1):

If they are going to be using remote desktop to configure these services, they have to be in the administrator group and thus will be able to control every aspect of the server. I'd suggest setting up the site for the friend and giving them FTP access only. Or looking into a cpanel or plesk software solution.